# How to use \exp_not:N and \exp_after:wN to prevent the expansion of \input in a expl3 list?

Tags: expansion, expl3, latex3, xparse

I have been working on the implementation of an environment (which never nests) and a command to save different parts of a document and use them within it later using a `expl3` list and`xparse`. So far everything went fine, it works OK, but, when analyzing the `.fls` file I noticed that something is not right. When writing auxiliary files and then call them from the list this is loaded twice in memory. The code I own (MWE) is this:

```
% arara: pdflatex : {action: nonstopmode, options: "-recorder"}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,xparse,fvextra,xcolor}%

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \elementin #1
 {
    \seq_count:c {l_savecontent_content_#1_seq}%
 }

\cs_new:Npn \clearlist #1
 {
    \seq_clear_new:c {l_savecontent_content_#1_seq}%
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addcontent}{m +m}
 {
    \savecontent_add_content:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\usecontent}{O{1}m}
 {
    \savecontent_use_content:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \savecontent_add_content:nn #1 #2
 {
 \seq_if_exist:cF { l_savecontent_content_#1_seq }
    { \seq_new:c { l_savecontent_content_#1_seq } }
 \__savecontent_add_content:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__savecontent_add_content:nn #1 #2
 {
    \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
  {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { l_savecontent_content_#1_seq } { ##1 }
  }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \savecontent_use_content:nn #1 #2
 {
    \seq_item:cn { l_savecontent_content_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { scontent }
 {
    save-cmd .tl_set:N   = \l_scontent_cmd_save_tl,%
    show-cmd .bool_set:N = \l_scontent_cmd_show_tl,% 
    save-env .tl_set:N   = \l_scontent_env_save_tl,%
    show-env .bool_set:N = \l_scontent_env_show_tl,%
    show-inf .bool_set:N = \l_scontent_inf_show_tl,%
    name-tmp .tl_set:N   = \l_scontent_tmp_name_tl,% 
    temp-ext .tl_set:N   = \l_scontent_ext_temp_tl,%
    body-env .bool_set:N = \l_scontent_env_body_tl,%
    verb     .meta:n     = { body-env = false },%
    show-all .meta:n     = { show-env = true , show-cmd = true },%
 }

\keys_set:nn { scontent }
 {
    save-cmd = content,%
    show-cmd = false,%
    save-env = content,%
    show-env = false,%
    name-tmp = \jobname,%
    temp-ext = tsc,%
    show-inf = false,%
    body-env = true,%
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Setscontent}{ +m }
 {
    \keys_set:nn { scontent } {#1}
 }

\newrobustcmd{\envtolist}[1]{\addcontent{ \l_scontent_env_save_tl }{{#1}}}

\newcounter{outNr}

\tl_new:N \filetolist

\NewEnviron{SAVEcontent}[1]{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{scontent}{ !o }
 { 
   \group_begin:
   \IfNoValueF {#1} { \keys_set:nn { scontent } {#1} }
   \IfBooleanTF { \l_scontent_env_body_tl } { \SAVEcontent{#1} } 
    { \stepcounter{outNr} \VerbatimOut{\l_scontent_tmp_name_tl-\theoutNr.\l_scontent_ext_temp_tl}}
 }{
   \IfBooleanTF { \l_scontent_env_body_tl }
    {\endSAVEcontent\expandafter\envtolist\expandafter{\BODY}}
    {\endVerbatimOut
    \tl_put_right:Nx  \filetolist { {\envtolist { \exp_not:N \input { 
    \exp_after:wN \l_scontent_tmp_name_tl-\theoutNr.\l_scontent_ext_temp_tl } } } }
    \filetolist
    }
  \IfBooleanT { \l_scontent_env_show_tl } { \usecontent[-1]{ \l_scontent_env_save_tl} }
  \IfBooleanT { \l_scontent_inf_show_tl } 
    {\marginpar{\scriptsize\ttfamily saved ~ in ~ \l_scontent_env_save_tl, ~ index ~ \elementin{\l_scontent_env_save_tl}}}
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Scontent}{!o +m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \IfNoValueF {#1} { \keys_set:nn { scontent } {#1} }
  \addcontent{ \l_scontent_cmd_save_tl }{{#2}} % pass direct to list
  \IfBooleanT { \l_scontent_cmd_show_tl } { \usecontent[-1]{ \l_scontent_cmd_save_tl} }
  \IfBooleanT { \l_scontent_inf_show_tl } 
    {\marginpar{\scriptsize\ttfamily saved ~ in ~ \l_scontent_cmd_save_tl, ~ index ~ \elementin{\l_scontent_cmd_save_tl}}}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\Setscontent{save-env=test-env, save-cmd=test-cmd}
\section{Test scontent env OK}
The following blocks of text will be stored directly in list or in external files and
then referenced using lists, not shown directly.\par

\begin{scontent}[show-inf]
\textcolor{red}{First Text}....use environ
\end{scontent}

\begin{scontent}[verb]
\textcolor{green}{Second Text}...save in \verb+\jobname-1.tsc+
\end{scontent}

\begin{scontent}[verb]
\textcolor{blue}{Third Text}...save in \verb+\jobname-2.tsc+
\end{scontent}

Now we can see that the number of items saved in the list is \elementin{test-env} and 
we can show them in reverse order whit \verb+\usecontent[...]{test-env}+:\par

\usecontent[3]{test-env}\par\vspace{0.5cm}
\usecontent[2]{test-env}\par\vspace{0.5cm}
\usecontent[1]{test-env}\par\vspace{0.5cm}

\section{Test Scontent comand OK}

\Scontent[show-inf]{using a \textcolor{orange}{\texttt{\textbackslash Scontent}}\ command version}
No \verb+\verb+ supported by environ :( [no problem, use env for this] :)\par
\usecontent{test-cmd}
\end{document}
```

The output of the `.fls` file is:

```
$ cat forum.fls |  grep \.tsc
OUTPUT forum-1.tsc
OUTPUT forum-2.tsc
INPUT forum-2.tsc
INPUT forum-2.tsc
INPUT forum-1.tsc
INPUT forum-1.tsc
```

and should go out:

```
OUTPUT forum-1.tsc
OUTPUT forum-2.tsc
INPUT forum-1.tsc
INPUT forum-2.tsc
```

that is to say when executing `\usecontent` should show only an`INPUT` in `.fls`, i think the problem is in the lines of `\filetolist` or `\addtolist` that expands `\input`when saving. An image of how it works:

[image: pdf image generated by pdflatex (TexLive 2018 up)]

I have read the documentation but it is at a level far superior to mine and I have not been able to find the solution to my problem.
Saludos

PS: Comments to improve the code are welcome

Comment: Too much code.  Please post a *minimal* working example.

Comment: I have tried to reduce it, what is written in the preamble is the minimum, thousand apologies

Comment: the duplicates you refer to are omnipresent in the fls file (from recorder option). They probably have nothing to do with the details of your code. Perhaps this is artefact of `\InputIfFileExists` LaTeX macro.

Comment: There are various things that are not 'standard' `expl3` here: none of them relate to the question itself ...

Comment: @JosephWright: Sorry, I was a little lost, I thought that when executing `\filelist` I would read the file at that moment, instead of having saved the line`{\input{file-1.tsc}` and that's why it appeared twice, hence my wrong idea of the use of `\exp_not: N` and `\exp_after: wN`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Can you clarify one thing (for the same code and you do not need a separate question)... in that they differ `\newrobustcmd` from`\NewDocumentCommand`, both are robust, but in this case they do not behave the same ... am I writing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon you observe in the fls file (from `-recorder`)  option has presumably nothing to do with your code. It is an artefact from LaTeX's `\input` when used in `\input{file}` form.

Consider this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-test}
This is a test file
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-test2}
This is another test file
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\input{\jobname-test}

\input \jobname-test2
\end{document}
```

and compile it with `pdflatex -recorder`. This creates an fls file, due to filecontents there will be multiple references to the test file but extracting the relevant lines I get this

```
....
INPUT filename.aux
INPUT filename.aux
OUTPUT filename.aux
INPUT filename-test.tex
INPUT filename-test.tex
INPUT filename-test2.tex
OUTPUT filename.pdf
....
```

As you can see the `\input filename` form creates only one entry but the `\input{filename}` creates two.

```
$ latexdef input

\input:
macro:->\@ifnextchar \bgroup \@iinput \@@input 


$ latexdef @iinput

\@iinput:
macro:#1->\InputIfFileExists {#1}{}{\filename@parse {#1}\edef \reserved@a {\noexpand \@missingfileerror {\filename@area \filename@base }{\ifx \filename@ext \relax tex\else \filename@ext \fi }}\reserved@a }
```

The `\InputIfFileExits` will open for reading twice the file, the first one to check existence.

On the other hand `\@@input` is TeX's primitive, which of course opens only once.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, changed to `\@@ input` everything goes perfectly. will it improve the runtime of the file? ....Saludos